# If $f$ is continuous at $0$ prove that $\int f\,d\beta=f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This is a part of exercise 6.3 from Baby Rudin.

Define $\beta$ as follows: $\beta(x)=0$ if $x<0$, $\beta(x)=1$ if $x>0$ and $\beta(0)=1/2$. Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[-1,1]$. Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $0$, then $\int f\,d\beta=f(0)$.

First we need to show that $f$ is integrable. That is, for $\epsilon>0$ there is some partition $P$ such that $$\frac{M(f,[0,x_i])-m(f,[0,x_i])}{2}<\epsilon$$
There is no harm in demanding that $0\in P$. I can choose partition as fine as $|x_i|<\delta$ for the $\delta$ corresponding to our $\epsilon$ such that $|f(x_i)-f(0)|<\epsilon$. But then what? Is there a theorem saying that as $x_i\rightarrow 0$, $M(f,[0,x_i])\rightarrow m(f,[0,x_i])$, or something like that?

Comment: The only intervals of the partition that contribute to the sums are the two intervals with $0$ as an endpoint. For all other intervals, you have $\beta(x_i) - \beta(x_{i-1}) = 0$.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I am confused about what to do afterwards.

Comment: Then you only need to estimate $\sup \{ f(x) : x_{i-1} \leqslant x \leqslant x_i\} - \inf \{f(x) : x_{i-1} \leqslant x \leqslant x_i\}$ for the two intervals with $0$ as an endpoint. The continuity of $f$ in $0$ deals with that.

Comment: Yes but how exactly? This is what I'm asking. I wrote "Is there a theorem saying that as $x_i\rightarrow0$, $M(f,[0,x_i])\rightarrow m(f,[0,x_i])$, or something like that?"

Comment: If $\lvert f(x) - f(0)\rvert < \varepsilon$ for $\lvert x\rvert < \delta$. Then what does that say about $M(f,[0,x_i])$ and $m(f,[0,x_1])$ for $0 < x_i < \delta$?

Comment: That both $M(f,[0,x_i])$ and $m(f,[0,x_1])$ are close to $f(0)$?

Comment: More. It tells you how close (at least) they are.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Can you find an upper bound for $M(f,[0,x_i])$ under the assumption $0 < x_i < \delta$?

Comment: $f(0)+\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes. And a lower bound for $m(f,[0,x_i])$ is derived similarly. That gives you a bound for $M(f,[0,x_i]) - m(f,[0,x_i])$ which does exactly what you need.

Comment: This looks so unbelievably easy and I feel incredibly stupid right now... Also found a lower bound for $m$, namely, $f(0)-\epsilon$ but still I can't solve it

Comment: You get $M-m \leqslant 2\varepsilon$. Ditto for the interval $[x_j,0]$. Then the difference of the upper sum and the lower sum is  at most $\frac{1}{2}(2\varepsilon) + \frac{1}{2}(2\varepsilon) = 2\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, $f$ is $\beta$-integrable (with $\int f\,d\beta = f(0)$).

Comment: Ok, finally got it, thank you very much. I think I need sleep